# ReactJS - setState working in a weird way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am trying to add things to a list, in the form of a state array. However, with my current code, the first item doesn't add itself properly.

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
      total: 0.00,
      ...
    }
  }

  //some unimportant code here

  addToList = item => {
    this.setState({list: [...this.state.list, item]});

    //This method call for a method that gets the total price of all the items
    this.getTotal(); 
  }

  //this method works fine, except with the first element
  getTotal() {
    this.setState(({sum= 0.0, items, list}) => {
      items.forEach(element => {
        if(this.state.list.length !== 0.0) {
          if(this.state.list.includes(element.name)) {
            sum += parseFloat(element.price);
          }
        }
      });
      this.setState({total: sum});
    });
  }
}
```

When I `console.log` the `list` state I get an empty array for the first item, and then the items are delayed by one. So if I add the item `A` and look at the console, I see nothing. When I add item `B` and look at the console, I see an `Array` with the item `A`. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? I probably wouldn't pass a method to setState? And then call setState inside of that method?

Comment: @dezman The getTotal method isn't the one I'm having issues with, I just added it so that you get a better idea of what the addToList method contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that **setState is asyncronous**, so if you wanna check the list updated, you have add a callback to the setState :

```
 addToList = item => {
    this.setState( {list: [...this.state.list, item]}, () =>{ 
     // So if you make anything here, you are sure that the state was updated successfully 
    console.log( this.state.list );
    this.getTotal();
    } );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Every access to `this.state.list` should be  replaced with `list`. `this.state.list` accesses potentially old state. The whole point of passing a callback is that you can access the current state passed as argument. You are doing this correctly for `items`, but not for `list`.

You should also `return {total: sum}` from the `setState` callback instead of calling `this.setState`:

```
  getTotal() {
    this.setState(({items, list}) => {
      const sum = 0;
      items.forEach(element => {
        if(list.includes(element.name)) {
          sum += parseFloat(element.price);
        }
      });
      return {total: sum};
    });
  }
```

For the same reason you should use a callback function in `addToList`:

```
 addToList = item => {
   this.setState(({list}) => ({list: [...list, item]}));
   this.getTotal(); 
 }
```